# How to create a better playSong method?

Tags: android, eclipse, playback

I want to play a song from an selected album.
The problem is whenever I click on an album, select the song, the playSong method plays the first song of course because of code part 2(down). Maybe you look trough my code and you can help me.Thanks a lot, Vinzenz

---

Part 1:

```
.
. 
.
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
.
. 
.
```

---

Part 2:

```
.
. 
.
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long Title ) {
      if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

        // getting listitem index
            int songIndex = position;
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent();

            // Sending songIndex to BrowseActivity
            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);

            setResult(100, in);
            // Closing PlayListView
            finish();


     }    
.
. 
.
```

Comment: What's your problem? Is the behavior not as you expected?

Comment: the problem is, that songIndex is never bigger than the total numbers of songs in the album i've chosen the song.For example: Artitst: me -> Album: best of: Songs, Song1,Song2,Song3. Then when I start playing a song, a song is played from all songs between 1-3.